# License plate probability

Tags: probability

I recently moved to a town of 100k (in 2002, no current figure available).

License plates are 4 chars and 1 to 4 digits. I started to notice a few with the same 4 digits (xxxx 8888, yyyy 3333, etc).

I am not deliberately looking, I just seem to notice some when I am waiting at one of the 4 traffic lights on my journey to work, or as they drive towards me.

My drive takes 10 minutes and can vary in start time by 15 minutes, so I am not necessarily seeing the came cars every day. I would estimate that I pass "several hundred" cars, certainly not as much as 1,000, and I am not scanning every plate that I pass (as I am too busy driving), I just seem to notice them somehow.

Today I saw SIX cars with such plates. What is the probability of that? And should I be worried that someone is bending the fabric if space/time?

(Nope, @ user45195, it's not a troll (can you vote me back up, please? Thanks), I was just being flippant (crossed with a little bit of wondering if I am living in a simulation)). It just seems incredibly improbable.

---

[Update] Ok, I am no mathematician, but here's my reckoning so far.

There are 9,999 possible 1-4 digit combinations. Nine of those can be 4 digit (no 0000), so the odds of any given car having an XXXX are 1 in 1,111. What are the odds of seeing six?

But how do I figure that out, given a sample of "a few hundred"? And to what extent should I consider that we are all commuting withing a relatively narrow time band - or does that even matter? Maybe I just need to consider the number of cars which I pass?

On the drive home I (only) noticed two such, which sill sounds like a million to [total number of cars seen, i.e a few 100]

[Update] I only saw one this morning, which is still surprising as I only passed a few hundred cars. However, at lunchtime as I walked across site 10 minutes from the canteen I passed about 10 cars (call it 20, if you want to, but I doubt it) whose plates had 4 identical digits.

Doesn't this seem highly improbable?

---

[Update] On Saturday I drove 1/4 to fill my tank, during which time I passed 4 cars with plates which had 4 identical digits. I could not have passed more than 20 cars. Heading home with a full tank, the first car which I saw had plate xxxx 6666 and the one following had yyyy 6666 (i was greatly relieved when the next was zzzz 888).

Only two on my way to work this morning, but I was concentrating deeply about work, so it is a wonder that I noticed any.

I *do* understand the point about perceived coincidences, but how can I be seeing multiple such plates every day when passing so few vehicles?

Comment: If you play lotto, you may want to include those 4 numbers!

Comment: If the number plates are actually random, the probability of such event is less than one in trillion. Obviously, some number plates are distributed more frequently, and you tend to notice them. Is this a troll question, considering the last line of your question?

Comment: Nope, not a troll. But I fail to comprehend your claim that "some number plates are distributed more frequently", other than perhaps they have an "end of run". E.G, they finish AAAA series before they get to 9999, but that hardly skews the curve enough to explain what I am seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the classic paper, [Methods for Studying Coincidences](http://stat-www.berkeley.edu/~aldous/157/Papers/diaconis_mosteller.pdf), by Diaconis and Mosteller, of interest.  Keep in mind, you tend to remember the days when you *do* see something striking, not so much the days when you don't.

Comment: Thanks, I did consider that. I am fond of pointing out to others that we tend to notice "remarkable" things and not mundane things (like the time I won the lottery, as opposed to all of the times that I didn't).  I only saw one today, which is still a stretch if I only pass a few 100 cars, even if my brain, unknown to me is subconsciously scanning every plate. I see several almost every day, but still wonder about SIX in a single day, in 20 minutes of moderate traffic, despite your invaluable reference ;-)

Comment: @Mawg On our parking lot, with about a 100 cars, there are 3 cars with the same initial 3 chars (in 3-char-3-digit plates, i.e. there are MAX 1000 such cars in Belgium, out of approx. 6M cars). How freaky is that. I'm with you on the space/time bending ;-)

Comment: In some countries the initial letter or letters indicate the city of registration, which would obviously skew the data heavily. Is that the case for you?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** the OP stated later that the combination 0000 is not valid, but that the digit 0 can be used. So I've changed my answer!

---

The total number of different plates is the number of possible combinations of 4 chars and 4 digits. Assuming an English alphabet and that there are no other rules (in my country, the plates don't use vocals in the chars), it would be 26 letters as a char, and 10 digits minus 1 combination, the 0000. So:
$$\text{total plates: }=26^4\cdot(10^4-1)$$

Then, the plates that have all digits equal are all the possible combinations of chars ($26^4$) counted 10 times (because there are only 10 digits, and all digits of the plate are equal). Again, remember that the combination 0000 is not valid, so there's only $10-1$ possible combinations. Therefore,
$$\text{plates with all digits equal: }=26^4\cdot(10-1)$$

So the probability of seeing such an event is:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
P(\text{seeing a plate with all digits equal})&=&\frac{\text{plate with all digits equal}}{\text{total plates}}\\
&=&\frac{26^4\cdot(10-1)}{26^4\cdot(10^4-1)}\\
&=&\frac{9}{9999}=\frac{1}{1111}\,\text{or }0.\overline{0900}\%
\end{array}$$

Comment: That looks impressive! But,aren't you complicating things by even mentioning the letters? I have not yet paid attention to them. IF we ignore them, aren't we just speaking of 9 XXXX combinations from a possible 9,999?

Comment: That's absoluty true! But I thought that it would be easier to understand the process when you take into account the letters (although, as you say, they're meaningless for the answer). In my opinion, when first understanding math it's better to understand the thinking process, and then, when you already have a grasp to it, simplify!

Comment: Also, I edited the answer to account that the combination 0000 is not valid (although I didn't know that from the beggining).